# Image Thumbnail in Web2py: Unable to display the thumbnail

Tags: python, image, thumbnails, web2py, web2py-modules

I have used the suggestion here http://www.web2pyslices.com/slice/show/1387/upload-image-and-make-a-thumbnail
to make a thumbnail of an image. 
I have got the thumbnail but I am unable to display it.

The following are my functions:
db.py :

```
db.define_table('uploads', Field('dataset', 'reference dataset'),

Field('filename', represent = lambda x, row: "None" if x == None else [:45]),

Field('image', 'upload', uploadseparate=True, requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY() and IS_IMAGE(extensions=('jpeg', 'png','jpg','tif')) ),
Field('thumb', 'upload', uploadseparate=True, requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY() and IS_IMAGE(extensions=('jpeg', 'png', 'jpg', 'tif'))))
```

default.py :

```
def makeThumbnail(dbtable,ImageID,size=(150,150)):
    try:
       thisImage=db(dbtable.id==ImageID).select()[0]
       import os, uuid
       from PIL import Image
    except: return
    im=Image.open(request.folder + 'uploads/' + thisImage.image)
    im.thumbnail(size,Image.ANTIALIAS)
    thumbName='uploads.thumb.%s.jpg' % (uuid.uuid4())
    im.save(request.folder + 'uploads/' + thumbName,'jpeg')
    thisImage.update_record(thumb=thumbName)
    return


def insertImage():
    response.menu = [
    (T('Home'),False,URL('default','experimenter')),
    (T('Manage Data Set'),False,URL('default','MDS')),
    (T('Manage Experiment'),False,URL('default','ME')),
    (T('Manage Workflow Element'),False,URL('default','MWE'))]        
    dbtable = db.uploads 
    record = None
    record = db(db.dataset.id ==  request.args[0],ignore_common_filters=True).select().first()
    form = FORM(dbtable, INPUT(_name='up_files', _type='file',
    _multiple=True, requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY()),INPUT(_type='submit')) 
    # The multiple param lets us choose multiple files.
    if form.process().accepted:
    #onvalidation checks the uploaded files to make sure they are only txt,         config, or log.
    makeThumbnail(dbtable,form.vars.id,(300,300))
    response.flash = 'files uploaded' 
    files = request.vars['up_files'] 
       if not isinstance(files, list): 
    #convert files to a list if they are not one already.
        files = [files]
       for file in files:         
         db.uploads.insert(dataset=record.id, filename=file.filename, image=db.uploads.image.store(file, file.filename))

        #store is a FIELD method that let's you save a file to disk.  you can choose the directory if you want using the 'path' param.
    else:
        response.flash = 'Choose the Files you would like to upload'
   return dict(form=form, record=record)
```

And then the view:

```
{{extend 'layout.html'}}
<h4>Manage Image of dataset: {{=record.name}}</h4>

{{if images:}}
<div style="overflow: auto;" width="80%">
<table>
<tr> <th> Image </th> </tr>
{{
    for image in images:
    =TR(TD(image.filename),  IMG(_src=URL('default', 'download',    args=image.thumb)), A(str(T('View')),_href=URL("show", args=[image.id,rowId])), A(str(T('Delete')),_href=URL('deleteImage',args=image.id)))}}
    {{pass}}
</table>

</div>
{{pass}}
```

Note: I am trying to display the the thumbnails for a each image in a list of images.(see the View).
I am not getting the thumbnail but rather small question marks in its place.
PS: i am unable to upload the image.
I want images in place of question mark. I am doing something wrong in insertImage() function and also in the view.
Thanks in Advance for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you appear to be conflating `FORM` and `SQLFORM`. The former is for creating custom forms (not connected with any database tables), and the latter is for building a form based on a database table (and therefore automatically handling inserts). You cannot pass a DAL Table object to `FORM` as in your code -- that will simply serialize the Table object to its string name, which will be included in the HTML form DOM to no effect. Further, in this case, `form.vars.id` will simply be `None` (`FORM` does not generate record IDs, as it does not do any database inserts).

Also, rather than directly saving the file in `makeThumbnail`, a better option would be to save the image to a StringIO object and then pass that object to `db.uploads.thumbnail.store()` (as you do for storing the original image). In that case, the `.store()` method of the thumbnail field will handle the file naming and saving automatically.

```
from cStringIO import StringIO
tmp = StringIO()
im.save(tmp, 'jpeg')
tmp.seek(0)
thisImage.update_record(thumb=db.uploads.thumb.store(tmp, filename='thumbnail.jpg'))
```

For more details, see http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/06/the-database-abstraction-layer.